# What element does Outlook adds for contextual add-ins to work in Outlook 2019 windows?

Tags: outlook, outlook-addin, office-js, outlook-web-addins

Outlook adds certain elements when a contextual add-in is trigerred. Like in case of web client (OWA), it adds a span around the regex matched expression and in case of Outlook for Mac, it adds an anchor tag around it. I was wondering what element does the Outlook adds for Outlook 2019 for windows?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: What scenario are you trying to achieve? We have APIs to obtain the highlighted entity. Is that what you are trying to obtain or are you just interested in the underlying tech?

Comment: I want to know the element that is used to highlight the entity in case of Outlook 2019 for Windows. I need to do some styling when the entity is highlighted using that element.

Answer (score 0):

Currently, Outlook does not have an API that exposes the element that highlights the entity. We track Outlook add-in feature requests on our [user-voice page](https://officespdev.uservoice.com/forums/224641-general/category/131778-outlook-add-ins). Please add your request there. Feature requests on user-voice are considered, when we go through our planning process.